# How can I get set the value of a class object that logs when console.logging an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

For example

```
class foo{
   constructor (params){
       this.name = params[0];
       this.blah = params[1];
   }
}

el1 = new foo(['name1', 'blah1']);
el2 = new foo(['name2', 'blah2']);
arr = [el1, el2];

console.log(arr);
```

The target output I'd like is:

```
[name1, name2]
```

But the current output is:

```
[foo, foo]
```

This is in the Google Chrome console.

Comment: You can iterate after getting the result. like this : https://jsfiddle.net/vzagu79k/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. Although the console is partially specified ([here](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/)), I don't think it requires any specific requirements on what the console shows for objects. From [`Printer(logLevel, args[, options])`](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#printer):

> **The printer operation is implementation-defined.** It accepts a log level indicating severity, a List of arguments to print, and an optional object of implementation-specific formatting options. Elements appearing in args will be one of the following:
>
> - JavaScript objects of any type.
> - Implementation-specific representations of printable things such as a stack trace or group.
> - Objects with either [generic JavaScript object formatting](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#generic-javascript-object-formatting) or [optimally useful formatting](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#optimally-useful-formatting) applied.
>
> If the options object is passed, and is not undefined or null, implementations may use options to apply implementation-specific formatting to the elements in args.
>
> **How the implementation prints args is up to the implementation,** but implementations should separate the objects by a space or something similar, as that has become a developer expectation.

*(my emphasis)*

Neither of the two "formatting" links above dictates a specific output.

You could give the console a hint about what you want using the [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) property, but the Chrome console implemenattion isn't required to use it (and in my tests, doesn't). The `Symbol.toStringTag` property is used by the built-in `Object.prototype.toString` to determine the name it uses in the `"[object XYZ]"` string it produces, so it would be reasonable for Chrome's console (or at least, some browsers' consoles) to use it, but again in my tests, Chrome's doesn't as of this writing.

Here's what that property would look like:

```
class foo{
   constructor (params){
       this.name = params[0];
       this.blah = params[1];
   }
   get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
      return this.name;
   }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class foo{
   constructor (params){
       this.name = params[0];
       this.blah = params[1];
   }
   get [Symbol.toStringTag]() {
      return this.name;
   }
}

el1 = new foo(['name1', 'blah1']);
el2 = new foo(['name2', 'blah2']);
arr = [el1, el2];

// For me, this still shows `foo` in Chrome's console
console.log(arr);

// But for example, this shows `"[object name1]"`:
console.log(String(arr[0]));
```

---

Although you can do what you like in your own code, I recommend sticking to standard conventions when sharing code with others, as it makes it easier for them to read and understand your code. The standard convention in JavaScript is that constructor function (class) names are written with an upper case initial character, so `Foo` rather than `foo`.